# Selecting multiple overlapping date ranges as distinct columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a few queries and combine their outputs with a union.
That however is eating up the CPU on my database server.

I want to remove the unions and combine them all into one statement if possible.

Here are the queries:

```
select [shift],p.wc, (sum(QtyMade) / sum(CREWHrs)) / (max(t.UNITPERHRS) / NULLIF(max(t.CREW),0)) effy ,'YTD' datefield 
from Prod p left join #dtl_temp t on p.PN=t.PARTN  
where p.wc in ('999') and [date]>= DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) 
group by p.wc,[shift] 

union

select [shift],p.wc, (sum(QtyMade) / sum(CREWHrs)) / (max(t.UNITPERHRS) / NULLIF(max(t.CREW),0)) effy ,'Prior Year' datefield 
from Prod p left join #dtl_temp t on p.PN=t.PARTN  
where p.wc in ('999') and ([date]>= DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) and [date] < DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) 
group by p.wc,[shift] 

union

select [shift],p.wc, (sum(QtyMade) / sum(CREWHrs)) / (max(t.UNITPERHRS) / NULLIF(max(t.CREW),0)) effy ,'QTD' datefield 
from Prod p left join #dtl_temp t on p.PN=t.PARTN  
where p.wc in ('999') and ([date] >= '2017-07-01' and [date] < '2017-07-13') 
group by p.wc,[shift] 

union

select [shift],p.wc, (sum(QtyMade) / sum(CREWHrs)) / (max(t.UNITPERHRS) / NULLIF(max(t.CREW),0)) effy ,'MTD' datefield 
from Prod p left join #dtl_temp t on p.PN=t.PARTN  
where p.wc in ('999') and ([date] >= '2017-07-01' and [date] < '2017-07-13') 
group by p.wc,[shift] 

union

select [shift],p.wc, (sum(QtyMade) / sum(CREWHrs)) / (max(t.UNITPERHRS) / NULLIF(max(t.CREW),0)) effy ,'WTD' datefield 
from Prod p left join #dtl_temp t on p.PN=t.PARTN  
where p.wc in ('999') and ([date] >= '2017-07-10' and [date] < '2017-07-13') 
group by p.wc,[shift] 

union

select [shift],p.wc, (sum(QtyMade) / sum(CREWHrs)) / (max(t.UNITPERHRS) / NULLIF(max(t.CREW),0)) effy ,'Prior Quarter' datefield 
from Prod p left join #dtl_temp t on p.PN=t.PARTN  
where p.wc in ('999') and ([date] >= '2017-04-01' and [date] < '2017-07-01') 
group by p.wc,[shift]
```

The output of that is:

```
shift   wc  effy                datefield
1       999 0.951558640486598   YTD
2       999 0.706728843730067   YTD
3       999 0.831153497545209   YTD
1       999 0.732836888916855   Prior Year
2       999 0.548579728223933   Prior Year
3       999 0.58957623455441    Prior Year
1       999 0.617329386562882   QTD
2       999 0.826112085298484   QTD
3       999 1.0719875569761     QTD
1       999 0.617329386562882   MTD
2       999 0.826112085298484   MTD
3       999 1.0719875569761     MTD
1       999 0.617329386562882   WTD
2       999 0.832089035926471   WTD
3       999 1.0719875569761     WTD
1       999 1.17254367493512    Prior Quarter
2       999 0.939448907844456   Prior Quarter
3       999 1.20640432761946    Prior Quarter
```

Is there a way for me to combine all those date ranges into a CASE statement somehow? Or do I need to create a temp table with the date categories (WTD,MTD,QTD,etc) with columns for "from" and "to"?

I'm not exactly sure how I can achieve this result without the unions.

The dates you see in the SELECTs come from a script that calculates them and creates the sql query.

Comment: why do you need to do this at the same time? for optimization, there are many aspects need to look into, based on the different name of `datefiled`, I think the result return by each part of the query is unique, you could try to use `union all` instead

Comment: I will change it over to union all as you and someone else suggested.
I tried the queries and the execution time was similar. But since union all is less expensive I will use that.

The output they produce is pushed into a chart. I guess I could send each select over to the server as a separate request and see if that will ease the load.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you will get results by below query: I think you are looking for group by grouping sets, or rollup or cube. Check which one fits for your requirement

```
select [shift],p.wc, (sum(QtyMade) / sum(CREWHrs)) / (max(t.UNITPERHRS) / NULLIF(max(t.CREW),0)) effy ,'Prior Year' datefield 
from Prod p left join #dtl_temp t on p.PN=t.PARTN  
where p.wc in ('999') 
group by grouping sets ([shift], p.wc,datepart(yyyy,[date]), datepart(qq, [date]), datepart(mm,[date]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could make separate columns for each date range, and only SUM rows that meet the date range criteria (untested, syntax might not be exactly right) ...

```
SUM( CASE WHEN ([date] >= '2017-07-10' and [date] < '2017-07-13') THEN QtyMade ELSE 0 END )
```

On newer versions of SQL Server you could also use `IIF()`

One side note, `UNION ALL` is less expensive then `UNION` because it does not eliminate duplicate rows.